# Sorting 2D-array as a whole

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array to sort as a whole using Java.

I have looked at the various links
[How to sort a two-dimension ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035447/how-to-sort-a-two-dimension-arraylist) using comparators.

But it always sorts on a specific element. I want to able to sort for the whole 2d array. 
For eg,

```
int[][] r = {{1,7,5},{1,3,5},{1,3,6}, {2,3,1}};
```

on sorting should give me

```
{1,2,3},{1,3,5},{1,3,6},{1,5,7}.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will suit your needs:

```
Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<int[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
        Arrays.sort(o1);
        Arrays.sort(o2);
        for (int i = 0; i < o1.length && i < o2.length; i++) {
            if (o1[i] != o2[i]) {
                return o1[i] < o2[i] ? -1 : 1;
            }
        }
        if (o1.length != o2.length) {
            return o1.length < o2.length ? -1 : 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the most compact version

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a custom Comparator which allows to compare two lists of integers according to your criteria.

You must first sort the lists themselves before you sort using this comparator.

Comment: `public static void sortArray(Integer myArray[][])
    { 
        Arrays.sort(myArray, new Comparator<Integer[]>()
        { 
        @Override 
            public int compare(Integer[] o1, Integer[] o2) 
            {
                    return o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]); 
            } 
        }); 
    }`


Here I can compare the arrays say based on a particular column, but how do i compare the whole array and get the result as desired? Thanks

Comment: (responding to an old version of the post) ```Integer.valueOf(o1.hashCode())``` An array's hashCode is (usually) derived from its pointer in memory via System.identityHashCode, and has nothing to do with the contents. This won't work, and boxing just so you can use .compareTo() is not a very efficient way of doing things.

Comment: Forget about the hashcode idea with the boxing it does not work..., the idea of first sorting sub elements, then the root, that was my message.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I'd do it in Java:

```
private static void sortArray(int[][] array) {
    // Perform initial sorting
    for (int[] subArray : array) {
        Arrays.sort(subArray);
    }

    // Sort each array by its contents (similar to string sorting)
    Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<int[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
            int length = Math.min(o1.length, o2.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (o1[i] > o2[i]) return 1;
                if (o1[i] < o2[i]) return -1;
            }

            // Longer arrays come after shorter arrays, but only if the rest is equal
            if (o1.length > o2.length) return 1;
            if (o1.length < o2.length) return -1;

            return 0;
        }
    });
}
```

The first step sorts all the arrays inside the 2D array, and then the entire array is sorted based on the contents of each array inside the 2D array. The comparator works similarly to what you might expect from a case-sensitive String comparator.

Comment: Watch for java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException here:
`  for (int i = 0; i < o1.length; i++) {
                if (o1[i] > o2[i]) return 1;
                if (o1[i] < o2[i]) return -1;
            }
`

Comment: Well caught, I'll fix that now